# weird issue - android app crashes at some of the device. why is it?

Tags: java, android

i have an android trivia app. some players get errors when they click on "new game".
for me it works fine, and for it works fine also for most of the players.

the problem is most of the times at galaxy devices, but there are same devices with the same version that everything works right for them.

here is the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sportrivia.hapoelbeershevatrivia/com.dimikit.trivia.SingleplayerActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: BannerAdImageURL (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, RemoteServer, ChatServer, CommonBackground, SyncFrequencyDays, NumberOfLevels, BackgroundMusic, BannerAdImageURL, BannerAdLinkURL FROM settings
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: BannerAdImageURL (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, RemoteServer, ChatServer, CommonBackground, SyncFrequencyDays, NumberOfLevels, BackgroundMusic, BannerAdImageURL, BannerAdLinkURL FROM settings
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
at com.dimikit.trivia.utilities.settings.SettingsDataSource.getAllSettings(SettingsDataSource.java:99)
at com.dimikit.trivia.SingleplayerActivity.initializeAllData(SingleplayerActivity.java:322)
at com.dimikit.trivia.SingleplayerActivity.onCreate(SingleplayerActivity.java:218)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
... 11 more
```

do you have any idea what is the problem?
thanks

Comment: To help You, we Need to see the code from Your database. But anyway, I detected a similar issue on some devices. The Problem is, that some devices can´t build the path and save the database automatically like shown in the most examples. I have fixed this Problem: If You save the database on sd path, create the complete Folder first, before creating database.

Comment: Are you using SQLiteOpenHelper? Is this happend after some database structure update? Did those users with failures had used application with minor database version?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is supposed to be some settings on that "Settings" table when the app starts. It seems as if some configuration process that must take place before the user reaches the new game screen is not triggering.

Answer (score 0):

as per your exception log, you are trying to read some settings from your custom table `settings` which doesn't contain `BannerAdImageURL` column.